# SharePoint 2013 workflow not showing up in the associated list's workflow settings page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, configuration, visual-studio-2012

I followed the steps mentioned by Prabath [See steps here](http://prabathf.blogspot.com/2013/02/installing-and-configuring-workflow-for.html)

However when I deploy the SP 2013 workflow on the server, I can't see it in the 'Workflow Settings' page of the associated list.

The `Register-SPWorkflowService` shell command was executed successfully. Still no luck!

Any reasons why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Found something quirky with Visual Studio 2012.

After some snooping found out that my Target List property has disappeared. I added that again and it worked. I could see my workflow in the list